# How to replace part of multiple html tag with different content depends on the given data

Tags: php, html

I need to replace multiple html tags. sample code below :

```
$html = "<p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  <visualcontent imgid='1' type='jpg'></visualcontent>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  <visualcontent imgid='2' type='png'></visualcontent>
</p>";
```

The output I needed to have is:

```
$html = "<p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  <img src='1.jpg'>


  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  <img src='2.png'>
</p>";
```

If you see :

```
<visualcontent imgid='x' type='x'></visualcontent>
```

was replaced with image tag. I'm clueless how to do this. please help.

Thanks

Comment: What did you tried so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can easily do this with [Simple HTML DOM Parser](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/index.htm)

Here's how:

```
<?php
include('simple_html_dom.php');

$htmlString = "<p>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  <visualcontent imgid='1' type='jpg'></visualcontent>
  Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.
  <visualcontent imgid='2' type='png'></visualcontent>
</p>";

$html = str_get_html($htmlString);

foreach($html->find('visualcontent') as $v){
    $src = $v->imgid;
    $type = $v->type;

    $v->outertext = '<img src="'. $src .'.'.$type.'" />';
}

$output = $html->save();

print $output;

$html->clear();
unset($html);
```

Will give you exactly what you are after:

> `<p>Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.    <img src="1.jpg" />    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book.    <img src="2.png" />  </p>`